# Retrieving model using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to retrieve the whole model from my database searching by an "id".
Which query is best to use in this case?

This is how my schema looks:

```
{ _id: 54b5ed4b967a4e3b96fe8a39,
  email: 'blabla@yahoo.com',
  __v: 0,
  deleted: false,
  createdAt: Tue Jan 13 2015 23:15:07 GMT-0500 (EST),
  shipping: {},
  profile: { picture: '', location: 'Romania', name: 'bla' },
  tokens: [],
  role: 'shopper'}
```

and what I have is: `54b5ed4b967a4e3b96fe8a39`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the type of `Model` that you are looking for, i.e. `Person`. Just do:

```
var id = "54b5ed4b967a4e3b96fe8a39";
Person.findById(id, function(err, person) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('oh no! error', err);
    }
    console.log('found person', person);
});
```

Documentation [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById)

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Now I would like to access person.mail but I get the response that it is undefined. Even though when I do console.log(person) I can see the schema. How can I access person.email?

Comment: `person.mail` or `person.email`? can you post the relevant portion of the `console.log()` and/or the schema declaration?

Comment: It worked, sorry. It was something else that was blocking it. Thanks so much!